# Code::Blocks не работает автодополнение

Tags: codeblocks

Скачал программу Code::Blocks, но не работает автодополнение, вот настройки code completion:[image: скрин]

Comment: только не "автозаполнение", а "автодополнение". Вообще то Code::Block долгое время в качестве стабильной версии предлагал достаточно старую версию, которая очень странно работала. Работает ли там сейчас дополнение - а кто его знает. я там никогда не видел нормального дополнения.

Comment: На правах рекламы предлагаю использовать IDE от JetBrains для вашего языка

Comment: а разве реклама разрешена?